# Call to Undefined Function Issue

Tags: php

So I have been attempting a test because of a recent failure in a mini project where I create a function inside an if statement and try to use it. I've tried using it within the if structure and outside the if structure but every time PHP gives me back an error saying "called to undefined function".

```
require 'testing.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
  if(!strpbrk($_POST['name'],'/[!@#$%^*}{};:?/')){

   $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);

   function test($thename){
    echo $name;
   }

   test($name);
   }else{
    echo 'Please only submit alphanumeric values and underscores.';
   }
    }else{
     echo 'Please enter a name.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't complaining about `strpbrk` instead of `test`?

Comment: Yes. It specifically says "called to undefined function test()"

Comment: Are you trying to call `test` from inside `testing.php`?

Comment: you are using **$thename** as a parameter but **$name** as variable in the function. might not solve the problem though

Comment: I bet if you take out `test($name);` in your example here, the code still blows up with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely calling `test` from inside `testing.php`. The easy way to tell is commenting out the call to `test($name);` in the file you've shown and observing the same error.

If you want code in `testing.php` to leverage an externally defined `test` function, then you need to define `test` before loading `testing.php`.

```
function test($name){ // @note Fix the parameter too..
  echo $name;
}
require 'testing.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
  if(!strpbrk($_POST['name'],'/[!@#$%^*}{};:?/')){

   $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);

   test($name);
   }else{
    echo 'Please only submit alphanumeric values and underscores.';
   }
    }else{
     echo 'Please enter a name.';
    }
}
```